# Rails 4: Ordering Users based on the *last word* in their `name` attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `User` model with a `name` attribute. In my `PagesController`, I want to set an instance variable equal to all of the User objects, but I want to order them based on last name. I know I can do:

`@sortedusers = User.order(:name => :asc)`

to order the users based on their `name` attribute, but how do I do it based on last name? (i.e. how do I order the Users based on the *last word* of their `name` attributes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Define a virtual attribute last name in your model

```
def last_name
  name.split(' ').last
end
```

and then

```
User.order(:last_name => :asc)
```

Comment: I don't think database order queries can be used with virtual attributes, that's why @hd1 suggested to use sort_by instead and storing the name separately.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest storing the users' last name separately. Barring that, you can use sort_by, like so:
`items.sort_by! { |a| a.split(' ') }` or something along those lines. Note, this most likely cannot be used straight, it's merely intended to point you in the right direction, as most of my answers are.